# Cohen Structure Theorem Hensel's Lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, power-series

I have a question about a comment occurred in the following former thread from MO:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309609/cohen-structure-theorem-with-explicit-equations

With the same setting as in the linked thread the questioner wanted to know how to construct the isomorphism

$$k[[t]][\alpha] \xrightarrow{\sim} k[[u]], \text{ where } \alpha^2 + a\alpha + b = 0$$

for general case.

According to @Mohan's comments one can reduce the problem to the case that $a=0$ and $b =t^mu$ with unit $u$.

What I don't understand is how ***Hensel's Lemma*** imply that $u$ has the shape $u = u(0)v^2$ for another unit $v$ with $v(0) =1$.

Indeed the equation become after the reduction step as above the shape $\tilde{\alpha}^2 +b=0$. But $\alpha \not \in k[[t]]$, so I don't understand why $v^2 \vert u$ and why $v \in k[[t]]$?

But I don't understand how exactly here Hensel was applied.

Remark: I'm working with following version of Hensel's lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

So essentially it states that a coprime factorisation of a polynomial over residue field coeficients can be pulled back.

Comment: If $char(k) \ne 2$ let $a(t)^2-4b(t) = t^m d(t), d(t) \in k[[t]]^\times$ then $d(t)/d(0) \in 1+t k[[t]]$ so $(d(t)/d(0))^{1/2} = \sum_{n \ge 0} {1/2 \choose n} (d(t)/d(0)-1)^n\in 1+t k[[t]]$ and $\alpha(t) = \frac12 (-a(t) \pm d(0)^{1/2} t^{m/2} (d(t)/d(0))^{1/2}) $. With Hensel lemma it seems you are assuming your polynomial splits $\bmod t$  so $d(0)^{1/2} \in k^\times$ ie. $\alpha(t) = \frac{-a(t)}{2} \pm t^{m/2} s(t)$ with $s(t) \in k[[t]]^\times$ and your polynomial is irreducible iff $m$ is odd. Finally if $m = 1$ then $k[[t]][\alpha(t)] = k[[t^{1/2}]]$ otherwise there is no such $u(t)$

Comment: @reuns: ah ok so $u$ is your $d(t)$ and $v= (d(t))/d(0))^{1/2}$, right? Essintially - if I understood your agument correctly - then if $f$ splits $\mod t$ then Hensel provides that the lifted roots $\alpha(t) = \frac12 (-a(t) \pm d(0)^{1/2} t^{m/2} (d(t)/d(0))^{1/2})$ must be different and then also $d(0)^{1/2} \neq 0$ must hold? Is this exactly the Hensel argument used here?

Comment: @reuns: what I don't really understand is why we here need Hensels lemma. indeed, the "Taylor expansion" $(d(t)/d(0))^{1/2} = \sum_{n \ge 0} {1/2 \choose n} (d(t)/d(0)-1)^n$ we get "for free" and then $d(t) = d(0)v^2$ if we set $v:= (d(t)/d(0))^{1/2}$. Where we really have this "input" from Hensel lemma?